# Can I compress intermediate topic (state store) used by KafkaStream in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

When using stateful processor, the states can also be stored in kafka.

For example, those topics with the names as the following:
`-repartition-x` and `-changelog-x`

Can I compress these topics, for example, with gzip, and KafkaStream will still be able to use them?

Comment: Yes. You can enable compression on those topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mathias pointed out, you can compress messages by setting the `compression.type` topic config in internal topic configuration. See https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/StoreBuilder.html#withLoggingEnabled-java.util.Map-

Alternatively you can also implement a custom Serde which does the compression.

Prefer the former as it will only be compressed in the Kafka topics and not in the state store. This avoids unnecessary compress/uncompress during processing.

Comment: Does this even apply for Quarkus Kafka Streams (3.7.2)? There is no such documented setting `compression.type`, and when set it doesn't reflect in the application configuration reported upon start.