# Can I compress intermediate topic (state store) used by KafkaStream in Kafka via producer settings?

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-cloud

I am working with a kafka cluster hosted in Confluent Cloud.

As per https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/client-apps/optimizing/throughput.html#compression, Confluent Cloud enforces `compression.type=producer`.

I want to compress both the internal `*-changelog` and output topics.

This question is similar to [Can I compress intermediate topic (state store) used by KafkaStream in Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56594637/can-i-compress-intermediate-topic-state-store-used-by-kafkastream-in-kafka), but the accepted solution is not valid for me, as the topic setting can't be changed in Confluent Cloud.

I have tried to set `producer.compression.type=lz4` in my KStreams app, but I don't see a significant change in the bytes retained in the topic.

The setting seemed to work when I tried with a local docker broker (the topics on the file system were smaller), but it doesn't seem to make a difference in the retained_bytes metric available from Confluent Cloud.

Is there a good way to validate that this is effectively compressing the messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out setting `compression.type=producer` is enough for compressing the `*-changelog` topics.
The amount of data in our testing environment was too small for the retained_bytes stats to show the compression, but it became apparent when we applied on an environment with more volume.